# angular2: Obserable<Response> response.json() after all subscribes are done

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I have a class which extends angular `Http` class, let's call it `MyHttp`.
I also have `MyJwtHttp` class which extends `MyHttp` class.

I want to be able to return the response as json the problem is that if I'm doing something like this:

```
myJwtHttp.request(..).map(res=>res.json()
```

and the implementation of the `request` method is:

```
class MyHttp extends Http {
    request(url,...){
        ..
         ..
    return super.request(url).subscribe(res=> doSomething(res))
    }
}
```

The problem here is that the `map` function is getting invoked before the subscriber of the `MyHttp` class. This causes the input of the `doSomething(res)` to be a json and not the response itself..

I have tried using `last` instead of `map` but it won't return the json to the caller of the request.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you want to `subscribe` to your request, and call `doSomething(res)` instead of using `map` on it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something with the request within your `MyHttp` class, I would use the `do` operator instead of subscribing on the corresponding observable:

```
class MyHttp extends Http {
  request(url,...) {
    (...)
    return super.request(url).do(res=> doSomething(res));
  }
}
```

In your case, the `request` method doesn't return an observable but a subscription object corresponding to the call of the `subscribe` method.

From the rxjs documentation:

> Invokes an action for each element in the observable sequence and invokes an action upon graceful or exceptional termination of the observable sequence.
>
> This method can be used for debugging, logging, etc. of query behavior by intercepting the message stream to run arbitrary actions for messages on the pipeline.

Regarding the execution order, I don't exactly know the implementation of the `MyJwtHttp` but if the `map` operator is used outside the `MyHttp` and `MyJwtHttp` classes, its associated callback should receive a response object and not the JSON content.